# Connect broken circles in a binary image in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have an image below that I am working with and I am wondering if it's possible to connect broken circles like the one shown in the center object of the picture attached. The circle is broken towards the bottom and I would like to connect those two end points, without filling in the image (such as using imclose) because I need the edge of the inner circle as well.

I hope you understand what I am asking for. Thanks.

[image: Broken Circles in MATLAB]

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if is this what you want. But with this code you get the contour of the circles. I used the function imfindcircles.

```
circles = imread('circles.jpg');
BW1 = bwmorph(im2bw(rgb),'close');
figure, imshow(BW1);
[centers,radii] = imfindcircles(BW1,[20 40]);
figure, imshow(BW1);
hold on
viscircles(centers, radii,'EdgeColor','b');
```